# How to create a custom post type in home page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an custom home page in my site. I want to add 3 custom post ares to update images, text and links. How it can be done in wordpress 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom post types in functions.php. [How to make custom post type!](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress) Then add custom loops to your static homepage template as follows for each post type:

```
// The Query
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'YOUR POST TYPE',
       'posts_per_page' => 1 (Or as many or as few as you want -1 shows all!)
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```